# Annotate combined subplots (patchworks?) as single plots using patchwork

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graphics, patchwork

I'm trying to figure out how to annotate combined patchworks as if they were individual plots.

I've got one patchwork consisting of three combined plots and another single plot. The final composite plot is the first patchwork on top and the individual plot on the bottom. I have no problem getting the layout I want, but when I use `plot_annotation`, it gives letters to every plot, whereas what I'd like to see is an A for the top plot (patchwork of three subplots) and a B for the bottom one (just a single plot)

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 1')

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 2')

p3 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(hp, wt, colour = mpg)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 3')

p4 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_bar(aes(gear)) + 
  facet_wrap(~cyl) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 4')

top_plot = (p1 + p2 + p3)
bottom_plot = p4
combined_plot <- (top_plot / bottom_plot) + plot_annotation(tag_levels="A")
combined_plot
```

[image]

What I'd like to see, rather than A-D annotations, is A for the top plot (plots 1-3) and a B for the bottom one (plot 4). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Update to say it's easily doable with `cowplot`, which is fine. But I'll leave this open to see if patchwork has a built-in way to do it.   `cowplot::plot_grid(top_plot,bottom_plot,nrow=2,labels=c("A","B"))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution is to create two complete patchwork plots, each with its own annotation. You have to put them each inside `wrap_elements` to declare them as complete patchworks for this to work. Thereafter you can combine them as you would combine ggplots:

```r
# Set theme for annotations
thm <- theme(plot.title = element_text(face = 2, size = 16))

top_plot      <- wrap_elements((p1 + p2 + p3) + 
                                 plot_annotation(title = "A", theme = thm))
bottom_plot   <- wrap_elements(p4 + plot_annotation(title = "B", theme = thm))

top_plot / bottom_plot
```

[image]