# Putting a common label for two R base graphics (sub)plots within a figure generated with the patchwork package

Tags: r, ggplot2, figure, patchwork

There is already an excellent explanation about combining two `ggplot` objects into one panel of a figure generated with the popular patchwork package here on [Annotate combined subplots (patchworks?) as single plots using patchwork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73562383/annotate-combined-subplots-patchworks-as-single-plots-using-patchwork).

I like to put a common label for two `R` base graphics together instead of having an invividual label for each plot like in the following patchwork figure:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(gridGraphics)

old_par <- par(pin=c(6,6))
simple.plot <- wrap_elements(~plot(1,1)) +
               wrap_elements(~plot(2,2))
  
  layout <- "AB
             CD"

svg('file.svg')
  wrap_plots(A = simple.plot,
             B = simple.plot,
             C = simple.plot,
             D = simple.plot) +
    plot_layout(design = layout) +
    plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'A')
dev.off()
```

Unfortunately, this still labels each plot individually instead labeling two plots together with a single uppercase letter.

The only alternative which came to my mind was to save the plots to a file and then include this file into the final figure, which I'm afraid is not very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of the `patchwork` package, I realized it offers a nice solution, by handing a vector of labels including empty strings to the `plot_annotation` function:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(gridGraphics)

old_par <- par(pin=c(6,6))
simple.plot <- wrap_elements(~plot(1,1)) +
               wrap_elements(~plot(2,2))
  
layout <- "AB
           CD"

tags <- c('A', '', 'B', '')

svg('file.svg')
  wrap_plots(A = simple.plot,
             B = simple.plot,
             C = simple.plot,
             D = simple.plot) +
    plot_layout(design = layout) +
    plot_annotation(tag_levels = tags)
dev.off()
```

This would label the first row in the figure with an uppercase 'A' and the second row with an uppercase 'B'.